# The chromatic number of a graph is at most its circumference

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

The chromatic number of a graph is at most its circumference: the length of the longest cycle in the graph. (Making an exception for forests, where the chromatic number is at most $2$ and the circumference is undefined.)

This can be shown as a corollary of the following theorem:

> If $G$ has $k$ distinct odd cycle lengths and $k'$ distinct even cycle lengths, then $\chi(G) \le k+k'+2$.
>   ([P. Mihók, I. Schiermeyer, *Cycle lengths and chromatic number of graphs,* Discrete Math. **286** (2004) 147–149.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0012365X04002249#))

If we assume that the longest cycle in $G$ has length $\ell$, then there are $\ell-2$ possible cycle lengths: $\{3, 4, \dots, \ell-1,\ell\}$. Therefore $k+k'\le \ell-2$, so by the theorem above $\chi(G) \le \ell$.

My question is this: **does this statement have an easier proof?** After all, the inequality between the chromatic number and the circumference is much weaker.

It is not hard to prove in the case $\ell=3$ (as seen in [this recent question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3232043/knowing-every-circuit-in-a-graph-is-a-triangle-prove-chig-le-4)).

Also, there is a short argument that any graph $G$ with $\chi(G)=k$ contains a *path* (not a cycle) on $k$ vertices: let the colors be $\{1,2,\dots,k\}$, choose a coloring such that any vertex of color $i$ is adjacent to vertices $1,2,\dots,i-1$ (for instance, the coloring that minimizes the sum of colors over all vertices will work). Then from a vertex of color $k$, we can go to a vertex of color $k-1$, from there to a vertex of color $k-2$, and so on until we get to a vertex of color $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more thinking, I found a simple solution. We get it very quickly from two results which are well-known in graph theory, though for completeness I will include their proofs.

> **Lemma 1.** A graph $G$ with minimum degree $k$ contains a cycle of length at least $k+1$.

**Proof.** Take the longest path $v_0, v_1, v_2, \dots, v_\ell$ in $G$. The vertex $v_0$ has at least $k$ neighbors, and all of them must be other vertices on the path, because otherwise we could extend the path and make it even longer. The *last* of $v_0$'s neighbors on the path must be at least as far as $v_k$ (since there's $k$ of them), so we get a cycle of length at least $k+1$ by following the path from $v_0$ to $v_0$'s last neighbor, then taking the edge back to $v_0$.

---

Conversely, if the longest cycle in a graph $G$ has length $k$, then it has a vertex of degree $k-1$ or less. What's more, in every subgraph $H$ of $G$, the longest cycle has length $k$ or less (if it's a cycle in $H$, it's a cycle in $G$, too). So $H$ must have a vertex of degree $k-1$ or less.

A graph with this property - every subgraph has a vertex of degree $k-1$ or less - is called [$(k-1)$-degenerate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)).

> **Lemma 2.** A $(k-1)$-degenerate graph $G$ has chromatic number at most $k$.

**Proof.** We induct on the number of vertices in $G$. When $G$ has $k$ vertices or fewer, we can $k$-color $G$ by giving all the vertices different colors.

Otherwise, let $v$ be a vertex of degree $k-1$ or less. $G-v$ is also $(k-1)$-degenerate (every subgraph of $G-v$ is a subgraph of $G$) and has one fewer vertex, so by induction $G-v$ is $k$-colorable. We can $k$-color $G$ by starting with the $k$-coloring of $G-v$, then giving $v$ a color distinct from the colors on its neighbors (which eliminates at most $k-1$ options).

---

Putting together the two lemmas: a graph with circumference $k$ is $(k-1)$-degenerate, so it has chromatic number at most $k$. The chromatic number is at most the circumference.